# Flickering GPGPU Particles Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, simulation, gpgpu, particles

I've created a particle simulation (thing) with Three.js. I'm super happy with the simulation part of it, but for some reason I get a lot of screen flickering when I run it. The effect is more apparent on some machines / graphics cards, but I've noticed flickering with all of them.

[Here](http://brenden-morales.github.io/ThreeParticles/) is the demo.
[Here](https://github.com/Brenden-Morales/ThreeParticles) is the source.

Things I've tried:

- Narrowing the visible range on the camera
- Removing transparency from the PointCloud material
- Make each "simulator" have it's own camera, scene and mesh (I really thought this would work)

None of these have yielded any less flickering, and I'm not sure what the next culprit is. Maybe the OrbitControls? Maybe it's got something to do with the texture rendering? Any Ideas?

Comment: Cool. I do not see any flickering on my laptop, intel hd4000 video

Comment: Cant see any flickering either. On Linux with a Intel Haswell Graphics Device. Or do you mean flickering as in z-Fighting of the particles when zooming far out ?

Comment: Nah, i've seen z-Fighting, this doesn't look like that (I think). It's more like every once in a while I get a full screen "flicker". The whole Three.js window like flashes empty for one frame and then goes back. I really thought everyone would be able to reproduce this, bummer.

Comment: No flickering here too, but today I noticed that it sometimes freeze for a few frames, which may be of the same source as flickering.