# Flickering and frame rate difference on different machines

Tags: google-chrome, graphics, three.js, webgl

I'm getting flickering on one machine and not another while running a large cloud of textured points (up to 1,200,000, though not all on screen at once) in Three.js using `Points` and a `BufferGeometry`, and custom `ShaderMaterial`. On the machine that flickers (my mid-2012 Macbook Pro, 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7, Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB) the frame rate oscilliates rapidly between about 7fps and 60fps. The hold up in frame rate seems to be in the render call; the flickering happens intermittently all along - sometimes going away for a few seconds, then flickering a few times or a lot, with seemingly no pattern. The other machine is my Windows graphics box (Intel Core i7-4790K 4GHz, GeForce GTX 970), which displays at a solid 60fps and no flickering.

While it seems obvious that my graphics box performs better, I don't know why such a sharp frame rate oscillation on my laptop, and why the flickering?

Here are a couple screenshots with the Chrome rendering tools stats in the top right:

**Screen shot from my MacBook Pro:** (note the oscillating frame rate)
[image: screen shot from my macbook pro]

**Screen shot from my Windows box:** (solid 60fps and no flickering)
[image]

Perhaps [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28971164/2441384) is related?

Comment: I've also seen performance oddities in WebGL on older MBP's. The new ones, better.

Comment: @bjorke - Interesting, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: this can be unrelated to the gfx rendering itself. People go for webgl and want performance not realizing the browser performs a lot of different tasks these days. Try to use the browser-build-in task manager to see what process is the bottleneck it could be anything from download,obtaining certificate or some forgotten script on background ... not to mention viruses... Another matter is that Note book can save power by reducing computational power